# Constraining X and Y Draggable Area

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, drag

I'm trying to limit the draggable area for a objects on my screen and I'm getting a few errors in my code - I was trying to keep it simple for now, just reset the the max x or y if the object gets dragged beyond those limits, but I'm still not having any success. I could really use some help with understanding how to do this.

```
    float maxDragX = 1000;
    float maxDragY = 700;

    Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3(eventData.position.x, eventData.position.y, distance);

    transform.position = mousePosition;                                 // set object coordinates to mouse coordinates

    if(transform.parent.gameObject == partsPanel)
    {
        transform.SetParent(dragLayer.transform);                       // pop object to draglayer to move object out of partsPanel
    }

    if(transform.parent.gameObject == buildBoard)
    {
        // Constrain drag to boundaries of buildBoard Code
        if(transform.position.x >= maxDragX)
            transform.position.x = new Vector3(maxDragX, mousePosition.y, distance);

        if(transform.position.y >= maxDragY)
            transform.position.y = new Vector3(mousePosition.x, maxDragY, distance);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant set a vector for position.x or position.y They are float just.
you have to change position completely

```
 float maxDragX = 1000;
    float maxDragY = 700;

    Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3(eventData.position.x, eventData.position.y, distance);

    transform.position = mousePosition;                                 // set object coordinates to mouse coordinates

    if(transform.parent.gameObject == partsPanel)
    {
        transform.SetParent(dragLayer.transform);                       // pop object to draglayer to move object out of partsPanel
    }

    if(transform.parent.gameObject == buildBoard)
    {
        // Constrain drag to boundaries of buildBoard Code
        if(transform.position.x >= maxDragX)
            transform.position = new Vector3(maxDragX, mousePosition.y, distance);

        if(transform.position.y >= maxDragY)
            transform.position = new Vector3(mousePosition.x, maxDragY, distance);
    }
```

Comment: Ah...okay I see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to assign a `Vector3` to a `float`

here

`transform.position.x = new Vector3(maxDragX, mousePosition.y, distance);`

and here

`transform.position.y = new Vector3(mousePosition.x, maxDragY, distance);`